# MS Teams emoticons missing

Tags: microsoft-teams

Sometimes MS Teams stops showing emojis/emoticons in the menu that pops up when you hover over a comment. Emojis that have been added are visible, though, and you can still select an emoji, you just have to do it blindly. It's annoying since I often use the thumbs-up icon.

[image]

I tried restarting teams and it doesn't fix it. This is not the first time it happens. It has happened 3-4 times already. It happens randomly and then randomly gets fixed.

Any idea what's causing it, how to fix, etc.? Does it happen for anyone else or am I the only one?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes it happens to me too. Restart helped. It is I think a resource handling problem within Teams. It is not a surprise that Microsoft does not know how Windows handles resources.
I think we simply wait for a fix.